# How to connect to SQL server through IP

Tags: sql, windows, windows-server-2003

I have a remote server that has win2003 installed

I can connect to the machine using remote desktop and am succesfully hosting a web app on the server

I need to connect to the SQL server on that machine using a sql compare tool that I have.

What are the steps that I need to take to be able to connect to the SQL server given that all I have is the IP address to the machine and admin login credentials

Comment: There's not really a difference in most tools between having a server name or IP address.  Are you writing code? Using a tool?  How are you trying to connect?

Comment: how can I connect to that server directly from the sql server express that is installed on my local machine? maybe I can test the connection that way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are trying to remotely connect to sql server using ssms or another client on a different machine, you need to do the following:

- open up sqlservr on server firewall
- open up sqlbrowsr on server firewall
- be concerned about security - if you can rdp/connect to sql w/o vpn, then so can other people - so you better make sure you have hardened environment and very strong passwords.

Comment: how can i open up sql server and sqlbrowser on firewall?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the specific access technology, different syntaxes for connection strings are needed. For the .NET provider, [the syntax](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server) allows for passing server addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample connection ADO.net connection.

```
imports System.Data.SqlConnection
...
dim cn as new SqlConnection()
cn.connectionString = "Server=192.168.1.200;Database=mydbName;user id=notSA;password=C0mp!3xPVVD"
cn.open()
...
'Do cool stuff
...
cn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Open up port TCP 1433 (Sql Server) on the remote server
And for your connection string jus use the IP Address for the Server, instead of using the computer name

You should be able to interchange between computer name and IP address without any problems, because the Computer Name gets turned into an IP Address anyway.