# How to connect my APP to SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have 1 PC (Windows Server 2003 + SQL Server 2008)

and 2 PCs (MS SP2 + my APP)

how I can let my APP connects to sql server 2008 on other PC My APP will connect to server to store data in SQL Server 2008 and read/delete/edit (basic operations)

what is the best way to do that?

NOTE: my APP is written in C# (.NET Platform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here:

[how to connect to another sql server database(server pc) in local area network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567460/how-to-connect-to-another-sql-server-databaseserver-pc-in-local-area-network)

[How to connect to SQL server through IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352661/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-through-ip)

From 
[Connection strings for SQL Server 2008](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) you have:

Connect via an IP address

```
Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;InitialCatalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

DBMSSOCN=TCP/IP. This is how to use TCP/IP instead of Named Pipes. At the end of the Data Source is the port to use. 1433 is the default port for SQL Server.